# library for angular to upload + read file

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, file-read

After searching for like 4 hours, I am just hopeless... As an Angular newbie, I was wondering about the following question:

Is there an Angular library to read the content of a file that you just uploaded from a form?

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4 hours..!!.  Ok you are looking for a library which can read file content after select that file? If it is you question then you can do it easily. See this example, hope it will help you. http://jsfiddle.net/200eoamf/1/

Comment: @Emran thanks for your link. But unfortunately it does not work for me. I am using Angular 2, with components (*.module.ts and *.component.ts), but not ng-app/ng-directive. So I have no idea how to implement the solution in my code unfortunately...